# Error: Cannot find module '@salesforce/client/formFactor' while testing my LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am getting this error: Cannot find module '@salesforce/client/formFactor' when I run jest test, But it works in a scratch org.

import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

import formFactorPropertyName from "@salesforce/client/formFactor";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of box [sfdx-lwc-jest](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest) does not provide a mock stub for @salesforce/client/formFactor and hence you are getting the error.

The easiest and simplest way is to implement a jest mock. If you are looking to just do this for one component and not globally use the below approach in your .test.js

```
import formFactorPropertyName from '@salesforce/client/formFactor';


jest.mock(
'@salesforce/client/formFactor',
() => {
    return { default: 'Large' };
},
  { virtual: true }
);
// rest of code
expect(formFactorPropertyName).toBe('Large');
```

If you have this in multiple components then you can follow below

You can create your own stub for this module in jest using [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) property in the jest.config.js file.

Below are the steps you will need to follow

1. Create a folder in your `test/jestmocks` in your project root. Usually under force-app if force-app is your default directory.
2. Create a folder path that is a similar name to the module you want to mock. In your case you will create a folder named `@salesforce/client`  under `test/jestmocks`
3. Now create a file with name `formFactor.js` and use the below code in the file

   ```
   export const formFactorPropertyName;
   ```
4. Configure your **jest.config.js** as below

   ```
   const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');
   module.exports = {
      ...jestConfig,
    moduleNameMapper: {
   '^@salesforce/client/formFactor$':
       '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/@salesforce/client/formFactor.js'
     }
   ```

   };
5. Import the module in your `<component>.test.js` as below

   `import formFactorPropertyName from '@salesforce/client/formFactor`;

Assign the mock value using in your test

```
formFactorPropertyName = 'Large'
```